# Remotely accessing SVN server installed on a Synology DiskStation

Tags: svn, network-attached-storage, synology

I recently purchased a Synology DiskStation and installed an SVN server on it. I can access it fine from anywhere inside my home network, however now I would like to be able to expose it externally.

My first idea was to port-forward port 3690 on my router towards the DS, but then I would need to know the external IP address of my router in order to be able to connect to the SVN server from the outside, and of course this IP changes any time my ISP decides so, so this is not a viable option.

Since one can access the DS remotely using the URL http://quickconnect.to/account_name, I was wondering whether there is a similar way of accessing the SVN server installed on it. Does anyone have experience with such a setup?

Comment: So noone used a Synology DS as SVN server before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you need to forward the port.
Then, I use this:

> svn://yournamehere.synology.me/svn

In your case, it is probably something like:

> svn://quickconnect.to/account_name/svn